# Were Jedi trained in using a blaster?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

We know how Obi-Wan Kenobi feels about using a blaster, in episodes III and IV he hints at his distaste for them.

After slaying General Grievous and tossing the blaster on the ground:

> So uncivilized.

When talking to Luke about Anakin's lightsaber in Episode IV:

> Not as clumsy or random as a blaster; A weapon from a more civilized age.

But despite this, in Episode III we see that he does have some prowess with using one, aiming properly etc.

Are the Jedi trained in using blasters or is training strictly to learning the ways of the force and lightsaber combat?

Comment: They can use the Force to help with aiming.

Comment: That's what I kind of figured, but didn't know if they had formal training in blaster combat along with this :).

Comment: they show abilities to use many other gadgets as well, i assume that a full course in jedi training will give them at least proficiency with a blaster, as well as pilot training, underwater training (shows in episode 1 they were prepared to go diving) as well as other training. especially if the force can help aim, simply taking a couple lessons with a blaster may be enough.

Comment: The Jedi Path manual makes no mention of ranged weapon training other than "Jedi Snipers" who basically throw their lightsabers at oncoming enemies and then use the force to retrieve them.

Comment: I always thought Obi-Wan is a bit of a buzzkill. He always reproached Qui-Gon for any fun thing, he hates flying, he doesn't like blasters. One would think he would prefer to spend his time alone on some forsaken planet on the Outer rim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Introduction

This answer is based upon my own recollection of books and movies in the Star Wars Universe, as well as references to certain articles and books.

### Kenobi shot first

Kenobi did indeed finish off Grievous with a precise, well-aimed blaster shot to the guts. While the movie seem to indicate some level of aiming being done (see screenshot), this may simply be one interpretation.
[image: Obi-wan shoots Grievous]

Thus, we turn to the novelisation of ROTS, for more info. The following passage is said shot being made, from the perspective of Master Kenobi:

> *As the bio-droid loomed over him, electrostaff raised for the
> kill, the hold-out blaster flipped from the deck into Obi-Wan's
> palm, and with no hesitation, no second thoughts, not even the
> faintest pause to savor his victory, he pulled the trigger.
> The bolt ripped into the synthskin sac.*

-Stover M., Revenge of the Sith, Ch. 15, p. 273.

This implies that the shot was not made with any deliberate thought, but simply made instinctively which, as we know, usually works really well when augmented by the force. While there is no explicit reference to Kenobi using the force to guide his aim, I'd say it's indicated that it did.

As such, I would say that Kenobi did not receive any extensive training in using a blaster.

### Did other jedi learn to shoot blasters?

[The Jedi Path](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_%28real-life_book%29), by Daniel Wallace et al., does not mention the use of Blasters or any kind of ranged weapon in the Jedi Training, as stated by @Richard in the comments. This indicates, if not proves, that Jedi do not receive any formal training with blasters. I would guess that their knowledge of blasters compares to an average adult's understanding of using firearms in our universe (i.e. point and pull the trigger) and perhaps a bit more, given that they are peace-keepers AND warriors.

There are, however, jedi who are proficient, if not highly skilled, in using blasters, for various reasons.

[Kyle Katarn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyle_Katarn), who started out as an Imperial Stormtrooper, certainly knew how to use one. As did [Luke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker), growing up on a desert planet with an aptitude for adventures, at least to some degree. There are of course more examples through the history of the Star Wars Universe (I can provide a more comprehensive list, if you wish?).